# Does a piece af mass with human-like heat exchange mechanisms, heats up in dry air with a temparature greater than that of the mass?

Tags: thermodynamics

Imagine a piece of mass (equal to the mass of an average person and with the same heat conductivity and ratio of volume and area of an average person) with inbuilt mechanisms to transport the intaken heat, due to the temperature difference with the surrounding dry air, to the inner mass, and to release heat to the dry air by means of letting water come out of the mass (the water inside the mass is kept constant by a water supplier).

What happens to the temperature of the mass?
The difference in heat uptake and heat release is, of course, dependent on the temperature difference, so is it right if I say that above a certain temperature the mass heats up, no matter how much it's cooled?

Comment: "*that above a certain temperature the mass heats up, no matter how much it's cooled?*" Why would it heat up no matter how much it is cooled? What do you mean by this question?

Comment: Persons have thermostatic control of core temperature.  That's VERY COMPLEX and makes the question unclear.  Air, water, person, rate of two different processes "heat uptake" and "heat release", and the imaginary piece of mass.   How many of those elements can you remove from this question?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it will increase in temperature if the rate that it can remove heat is less than the rate that it has heat supplied.

Comment: That's not entirely true.   An ice cube can melt and stay at constant temperature with heat input, and no heat removed.

Comment: Sorry, he described it as a human like system so I assumed we weren't really at the freezing temperature of the fluids.